# How can I get id_token in identity server, before redirecting to client?

Tags: asp.net-core, identityserver4

After the user successfully signed in and before redirecting him to the client site I want to store the id_token in db. Actually the id_token is available in the client side but I don't know how to get it on the login process of identity server.
I would appreciate any help.

Answer (score 2):

You can create a custom [ITokenService](https://github.com/IdentityServer/IdentityServer4/blob/master/src/IdentityServer4/src/Services/ITokenService.cs) by inheriting [DefaultTokenService](https://github.com/IdentityServer/IdentityServer4/blob/master/src/IdentityServer4/src/Services/Default/DefaultTokenService.cs) and store Id_token after creation.

```
public class CustomTokenService : DefaultTokenService
{
    public CustomTokenService(
        IClaimsService claimsProvider, 
        IReferenceTokenStore referenceTokenStore, 
        ITokenCreationService creationService,  
        IHttpContextAccessor contextAccessor, 
        ISystemClock clock, 
        ILogger<DefaultTokenService> logger)
     : base(claimsProvider, referenceTokenStore, creationService, contextAccessor, clock, logger)
    {
    }

    public override async Task<string> CreateSecurityTokenAsync(Token token)
    {
        strign jwt = await base.CreateSecurityTokenAsync(token);

        // store token

        return jwt;
    }
}
```

And also you need to register `CustomTokenService`

```
builder.Services.TryAddTransient<ITokenService, CustomTokenService>();
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use one of the built-in events : [TokenIssuedSuccessEvent](http://docs.identityserver.io/en/latest/topics/events.html)  :

Modify your `Startup.cs` :

```
services.AddIdentityServer(options =>
{
    options.Events.RaiseSuccessEvents = true;
});
```

Create your custom `IEventSink` :

```
public Task PersistAsync(Event evt)
{
    if (evt.Id.Equals(EventIds.TokenIssuedSuccess))
    {
        var _test = evt as TokenIssuedSuccessEvent;
        var tokens = _test.Tokens.ToList();
    }

    return Task.CompletedTask;
}
```

Then you can find id token by checking type of each `tokens` .

At last register the event in `Startup.cs`:

```
services.AddScoped<IEventSink, MyEventSink>();
```

Comment: thank you for your response, the token value I get is like `****x9sA`. how can I have the full character of it?

Comment: @ElyasEsna ,identity server  obfuscates a token. see source code [here](https://github.com/IdentityServer/IdentityServer4/blob/44651bea9b02c992902639b21205f433aad47d03/src/IdentityServer4/src/Events/Infrastructure/Event.cs#L134) .  If needed , just create your own [TokenIssuedSuccessEvent](https://github.com/IdentityServer/IdentityServer4/blob/44651bea9b02c992902639b21205f433aad47d03/src/IdentityServer4/src/Events/TokenIssuedSuccessEvent.cs)

Comment: any reason behind that? if I write my own, am I opening a security hole?

Comment: IMO ,I don't think that is big security hole on server side .